# mongoimport failed to read csv file with reason "The handle is invalid"

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a csv file using mongoimport. Below is the code:
    mongoimport --db donorschoose --collection projects --type csv --headerline --file sampledata.csv

I'm getting the below error message:

Failed: read sampledata.csv: The handle is invalid.

I already searched the net, but unfortunately not able to find a solution for it.

Comment: You may need to use the full file path rather than just the name.

Comment: Thanks that worked... :-). But I was in the same file path in windows prompt... not sure why it did not find the file.. I would expect file not found error. Anyway thanks again..

Comment: @Brody you want to make your comment the answer? It just saved me too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the full file path and not just the name.